# Changing onClick function of React Component to React.FC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tsx

I have a Tab component which is a part of tabs structure, but I need to convert it into React.FC. Here is the original and below is what I've done so far, but I'm getting lost around the onclick functionality.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Tab extends Component {
 static propTypes = {
      activeTab: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    onClick = () => {
      const { label, onClick } = this.props;
      onClick(label);
    }

    render() {
      const {
        onClick,
        props: {
          activeTab,
          label
        }
      } = this;

      let className = 'tab-list-item';

      if (activeTab === label) {
        className += ' tab-list-active';
      }

      return (
        <li
          className={className}
          onClick={onClick}
        >
          {label}
        </li>
      );
    }
}

export default Tab;
```

Here is my very bad attempt, which obviously is very bad

```
import React from 'react';

/**
 * @function Tab
 */
 const Tab: React.FC = () => {
  

  type Props = {
    activeTab: string;
    label: string;
  }

    const onClick = (props) => {
      const { label, onClick } = props;
      onClick(label);
    }

    const {
      onClick,
      props: {
        activeTab,
        label
      }
    } = this;

      let className = 'tab-list-item';

      if (activeTab === label) {
        className += ' tab-list-active';
      }

      return (
        <li
          className={className}
          onClick={onClick}
        >
          {label}
        </li>
      );
    
}

export default Tab;
```

Any help would be much much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using typescript, you can define all the component props inside a type/interface and give it to the React.FC type, for example:

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  activeTab: string;
  label: string;
  onClick: (label: string) => void; // this means that the onClick param is a function that takes a label of type string as function parameter
}

// here we create a React functional component and we pass the Props interface to specify the component props

const Tab: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const handleOnClick = () => {
    props.onClick(props.label)
  }

  let className = 'tab-list-item';

  if (props.activeTab === props.label) {
    className += 'tab-list-active';
  }

  return (
    <li
      className={className}
      onClick={props.handleOnClick}
    >
      {props.label}
    </li>
  );  
}

export default Tab;
```

If you know how to destructor an object you can clean your function in this way:

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  activeTab: string;
  label: string;
  onClick: (label: string) => void; // this means that the onClick param is a function that takes a label of type string as function parameter
}

// here we create a React functional component and we pass the Props interface to specify the component props

const Tab: React.FC<Props> = ({activeTab, label, onClick}) => {
  const handleOnClick = () => {
   onClick(label)
  }

  let className = 'tab-list-item';

  if (props.activeTab === label) {
    className += 'tab-list-active';
  }

  return (
    <li
      className={className}
      onClick={handleOnClick}
    >
      {label}
    </li>
  );  
}

export default Tab;
```

Comment: Personally I prefer to assign the type to the arguments instead of using `React.FC`.  There's nothing wrong with your answer, but this also works: `const Tab = ({activeTab, label, onClick}: Props) => {`.